# Adding one Item to linked list creates two Items?

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list, stack, microcontroller

I'm trying to develop a device to copy files from one USB-drive to another, with both using the FAT-Filesystem. Therefor I use the "Vinculum II" microcontroller by FTDI. The Code is written in C.

To be able to copy all files, I need to know the names of the (sub-)directories on the drive because each of them has to be treated separately. There is a on-chip function to scan the current directory for files and sub-directories ('fat_dirTableFindFirst()' and 'fat_dirTableFindNext()').

I need to store the names of all directories (data type char *) which I received from the scan dynamically. I decided to use a linked-list. I use it like a stack (LIFO).

It's important for understanding the code, so I'll stress it again, that I have to scan each directory separately. So at first, I scan the root directory for its entries. Those ones that are further sub-directorys get pushed onto the stack.

After finishing the scan in the first directory, I grab the upper sub-directory off the stack (pop()). Then, I push the place marker "space" onto the stack, to be able to identify later, that I went into a deeper level/layer of that "directory-tree". If I don't find further directories during a scan, I move back to the last level and so on. Hence the scanning procedure should be similar to preorder traversing of a tree.

It works perfectly if there is max. one sub-directory in each directory. But if there are more than one, I get a confusing error: The first directory is pushed correctly, but all following entries appear **twice** on the stack! Because of that, the controller copies the same files again and again.

Single stepping through the program doesn't clearify why it happens. The code also writes the content of the stack before and after every push or pop into a .txt file with the same confusing results. It looks a bit like a push()-operation creates two Items, but only if it's called during that do...while loop.

Here's the interesting part of the code. vos_free() und vos_malloc() is equivalent to the usual free() an malloc() calls (ordner is the German word for directory or folder):

```c
 struct ordner {
           char* data;
           struct ordner* next;
           };

    void push(struct ordner** headRef, char* dirName) 
    {
       struct ordner* newOrdner;
       if (newOrdner = vos_malloc(sizeof(struct ordner)) != NULL)
       {
          newOrdner->data = dirName;
          newOrdner->next = *headRef;
          *headRef = newOrdner;     
       }
    }

    char* pop(struct ordner** headRef)
    {
       struct ordner* temp;
       char* value = "            ";

       temp = *headRef;
       value = *headRef->data; // "save" last element to return it

      *headRef = temp->next;
       vos_free(temp); 
       return (value);
    }

    while(1)
    {               
        file_context_t fileToCopy; // File-Handle
        struct ordner dummy;
        struct ordner* head = &dummy;
        dummy.next = NULL;
        dummy.data = begin;

        newScan:    fat_dirTableFindFirst(fatContext1, &fileToCopy);                    if(firstRun == 0) // First filename in first scan is the name of the disk, and has to be ignored
            {
                 fat_dirTableFindNext(fatContext1, &fileToCopy);
                      firstRun = 1;
            }

            do
            {
            // if the entry is a Directory, add it to the stack
                if (fat_dirEntryIsDirectory(&fileToCopy) == 1)
                {
                   strncpy(nextDir, (char*) &fileToCopy, 11);
                   push(&head, nextDir);                                        

    // The next if-statement usually cannot be true, because there can't be 
    // two files with the same name in one directory and the different levels/layers
    // of sub-directories are separated by a place marker, but actually it becomes
    // true (LEDs are flashing because of blink(3))
                     if (head->data == head->next->data) blink(3);
                } 
                else
                {
                    strncpy(nextFile, (char*) &fileToCopy, 11);
                     copyFile(fatContext1,fatContext2, nextFile);                       }
            } while (fat_dirTableFindNext(fatContext1, &fileToCopy) == FAT_OK); // perform scan, until all items of the directory were scanned              

    // then the next (sub-)directory has to be opened to scan it
    // there are two possibilities to proceed:
    //  (1) no directory found ("space" on stack) --> go back to last layer and open & scan the next directory there (if there is another one) 
    //  (2) a new sub-directory was found --> open & scan it

 change_layer: if (head != NULL)                
        {           
            nextDir = pop(&head); // get next Directory from stack

           // Possibility (1)
           if (nextDir == space) 
           {
                   // move back to last Directory
                   goto change_layer;
           }                    
           // Possibility (2): neue Unterordner gefunden
           else
                {
               push(&head, space); // sign for entering next layer
                    //...
                    // open next directory
                    //...
               goto newScan;
            }                       

          } 
       }            
    } // End while(1)
```

Can you tell me why it happens that one item appears twice on the stack? Is my Algorithm wrong?

After hours and hours of reasearching and coding I couldn't solve that problem.

Please forgive me my bad programming style with those assembler-like loops and my bad English (I'm from Germany :) )

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the declaration of a node for the linked list:

```
struct ordner {
       char* data;
       struct ordner* next;
       };
```

So, the `data` has no storage associated with it.  It is simply a pointer.

Then in your loop I do not see you call `strdup()` to allocate memory for a copy of the filename.  You seem to be passing some buffer address directly to `push()` which saves a copy.  This is a mistake.

I recommend that you change `push()` to call `strdup()` and save the filename.  Then when you free an instance of `ordner` you must free `data`, the duplicate string, before you free the `ordner` instance.

Since in your design `pop()` also frees memory, you should change `pop()` so that the caller provides a buffer, and `pop()` copies the filename to the buffer before freeing the memory of the popped `ordner` instance.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I immediately understood what I did wrong. Now the stack works fine :)

The system doesn't know strdup() but I just manually allocated memory and copy the string.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. <^_^>

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where `nextDir` is declared, but at first glance, this seems likely:

You `strncpy` a directory name into `nextDir`. Then, you push this onto the stack. You now have for example an entry with data "dir1" on the stack.

If there is another directory within the same directory, you `strncpy` the next directory name into the *same* `nextDir` buffer, effectively overwriting it. You push it onto the stack. Its data pointer becomes the *same* `nextDir` buffer.

Now, both entries have the same data pointer, and the value is the value of the *second* entry, so the stack looks like "dir2","dir2".

If you want to have a string in each entry on the stack, you need to allocate the memory for each one (make sure you free it eventually though!)

Comment: Thank you! Now I finally start understanding my mistake

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can declare variable like this within a while loop.  The compiler might give you the same pointer over and over again.

```
while(1)
    {               
        file_context_t fileToCopy; // File-Handle
        struct ordner dummy;
        struct ordner* head = &dummy;
```

Comment: actually it works. If the programm runs as it should, I only pass that passage of the code once before the data gets copied